# Jump to pattern without overriding search

Tags: search, functions

I'm trying to implement a mapping for making the vim cursor jump to a pre-defined search pattern without overriding the current search, but it is falling short in multiple ways:

```
function! JumpToBlockEnd()
    let search = @/
    let @/ = '\%^\|^# ----------'   "predefined search pattern
    normal n
    let @/ = search
endfunction
noremap m] :call JumpToBlockEnd()<CR>
```

1. It isn't accepting a count. I would like to be able to do something like `3m]` to jump to the third occurrence of the pattern
2. It exits visual mode. If I want to highlight text from the current position to the intended jump pattern position, I want to be able to do `vm]` to continue with visual highlighting
3. This is a minor issue, but if there was a search pattern prior to executing the function that was called with reverse lookup `?` instead of forward lookup `/`, it reassigns that pattern always to the forward lookup `/`.

I'm making the above specific mapping to enable block-like editing and execution in vim, sort of like jupyter notebook. Here's the file I'm testing this function on:

```
x = 3
y = 4

# ---------- [block] ----------:

hi = 'hi'

hi = 'hi'
# ---------- [end] ----------:

hey = 'hey'
```

**Edit**: Based on the accepted answer below, I created a function that takes the pattern as an input and can also be passed flags, enabling reverse search:

```
function! JumpToPattern(count, visual, pattern, flags)
    if a:visual
        normal! gv
    endif
    for _ in range(a:count)
        call search(a:pattern, a:flags)
    endfor
endfunction
nnoremap m] :<c-u>call JumpToPattern(v:count1, 0, '\%$\\|^# ----------', '')<cr>
xnoremap m] :<c-u>call JumpToPattern(v:count1, 1, '\%$\\|^# ----------', '')<cr>
nnoremap m[ :<c-u>call JumpToPattern(v:count1, 0, '\%^\\|^# ----------', 'b')<cr>
xnoremap m[ :<c-u>call JumpToPattern(v:count1, 1, '\%^\\|^# ----------', 'b')<cr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `search()` function (see `:help search()`)

```
function! JumpToBlockEnd(count, visual)
    if a:visual
        normal! gv
    endif
    for _ in range(a:count)
        call search('\%^\|^# ----------')
    endfor
endfunction

nnoremap m] :<c-u>call JumpToBlockEnd(v:count1, 0)<cr>
xnoremap m] :<c-u>call JumpToBlockEnd(v:count1, 1)<cr>
```

Here, we distinguish normal and visual maps because we need to re-enter visual mode upon calling the function (`gv`).

If your vim is new enough you can use `<Cmd>`, which is simpler

```
function! JumpToBlockEnd(count)
    for _ in range(a:count)
        call search('\%^\|^# ----------')
    endfor
endfunction

noremap m] <Cmd>call JumpToBlockEnd(v:count1)<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address the limitations 1. and 2 (it doesn't accept a count and it breaks visual mode). It does however address limitation 3

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh please see the edits