# How to call incremental forward/reverse search inside function in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, search, highlight

I'm trying to implement a search function that finds a pattern and jumps to it without overriding the current searched for & highlighted pattern.

Specifically, I want to be able to type out the pattern and jump to it just like how `/` and `?` are implemented in neovim; where when I start typing it immediately starts highlighting & jumping in real time. The only difference is that after jumping, I want to keep the previous highlighted/searched for pattern.

I took a look at several pages including [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/34605/27301), but the problem is that these solutions only seem to work with pre-specified patterns, whereas in my case I want to type out the pattern via `/` or `?`.

One solution may be to write a function that stores current pattern, calls `/`/`?` and after jumping replaces the pattern.

```
function! ForwardJumpToPattern()                                                                                                                                                              
    let search_original_content=@/                                                                                                                                                          
    normal! /  
    let @/=search_original_content                                                                                                                                                                    
endfunction
```

But the problem is that I can't figure out how to call `/` or `?` from inside a function.

Comment: why not use the `search()` function?

Comment: I tried that, but it is not interactive like searching via `/` or `?`

Comment: Turns out it is interactive in neovim, not vim. I edited the Q

Comment: so you want the 'incsearch' option setting, not interactive. But I don't understand, I thought you already have the search term? If you know the pattern and the searchterm, you can use `matchadd()` to highlight the pattern

Comment: @christian I dont have the search term already, otherwise the search function would work. And yes! Thanks for correcting the terminology. Can I call incsearch from within a function?

Comment: that might be a bit tricky, because of `:h function-search-undo`. You may be able to get around this by using `:call feedekeys("/search-term\<cr>", 't')`, the `t` is important here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `search()` function.

Call:

- `search(pattern)` to simulate `/pattern`
- `search(pattern, 'b')` to simulate `?pattern`

Comment: It's not interactive like when i search via `/` or `?`. Perhaps that is because I'm using the latest neovim and not regular vim?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by interactive. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I just realized that in vim it is not interactive. I'm using neovim. When I begin typing out characters after `/` in neovim, it immediately starts to highlight the results (before I hit enter), whereas in vim it only highlights and jumps to the results after carriage return.

Comment: I edited the question to specify this